# Inbox e achievements não estão atualizando

Tags: bug, stackexchange-button

Nas últimas 3 horas o inbox e o achievement pararam de ser atualizados, veja um exemplo:

[image: stackmenu vs aba de score]

Eu recebi +25 nas últimas ~3 ou ~4 horas, mas no StackMenu (StackExchange-button) só aparece os eventos anteriores a isto.